# In Java, how do you generate every possible combination of an NxM boolean array?

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, combinations

I'm trying to create a function that computes all possible NxM combinations of a 2D NxM array. It would be able to take in any two integers between 1 and N inclusively (so performing this action for 1x1, 2x2, 1x2, 2x1, ... NxM should be possible). I keep trying different solutions but can't seem to compute them all. Here is what I have so far:

```
    private static void computeGrid(int[][] B) {
        computeGrid(B,0,0);
    }

    private static void computeGrid(int[][] B, int x, int y) {
        print(B);
        int[][] B0x = copy2DArray(B);
        int[][] B0y = copy2DArray(B);
        int[][] B1x = copy2DArray(B);
        int[][] B1y = copy2DArray(B);
        if(x+1 < B0x.length) {
            B0x[x][y] = 0;
            computeGrid(B0x, x+1,y);
        }
        if(y+1 < B0y[0].length) {
            B0y[x][y] = 0;
            computeGrid(B0y, x, y+1);
        }
        if(x+1 < B1x.length) {
            B1x[x][y] = 1;
            computeGrid(B1x, x+1, y);
        }
        if(y+1 < B1y[0].length) {
            B1y[x][y] = 1;
            computeGrid(B1y, x, y+1);
        }
    }
```

For example, if have a 2x2 array (of integers representing this), I'd expect the following:

```
{{0,0},{0,0}}, {{0,0},{0,1}}, {{0,0},{1,0}}, {{0,0},{1,1}}, 
{{0,1},{0,0}}, {{0,1},{0,1}}, {{0,1},{1,0}}, {{0,1},{1,1}}, 
{{1,0},{0,0}}, {{1,0},{0,1}}, {{1,0},{1,0}}, {{1,0},{1,1}}, 
{{1,1},{0,0}}, {{1,1},{0,1}}, {{1,1},{1,0}}, {{1,1},{1,1}}
```

However, what I'm getting is this:

```
{{0,0},{0,0}},
{{0,0},{1,0}},
{{0,1},{0,0}},
{{1,0},{0,0}},
{{1,0},{1,0}},
{{1,1},{0,0}}
```

How can I go about computing all of the combinations?

Comment: Are you limited to c-style arrays?

Comment: Is N always greater than or equal to M?

Comment: @NomadMaker *"1x1, 2x2, 1x2, 2x1, ... NxM should be possible"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think about it, you can see a matrix as an one-dimensional list where each element has the position `m*N + n`; `m` is the index of the row, `n` is the index in the row and `N` is the amount of elements in a row.

Seeing a matrix as a list reduces the problem into getting all variations `(2^(M*N))` of a list with size `M*N` that only contains `0`s and `1`s.

We can make use of recursion to get all variations by recursively adding the `0`s and `1`s to each variation. The recursion starts with an empty list. Then the list is copied. A `0` is added to the original list and a `1` to the copied list. When we repeat that process with the resulting lists until they reach `M*N`, we get the set of variations.

When we have those variations, we can get the arrays out of it, where each array is a row in the matrix variation. We can get the index of the row an element belongs to and the index of the position in the row from the position in the variation list.

Here I've implemented that algorithm:

```java
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Deque;

class Main {

    static void addVariations(Deque<int[]> stack, int[] variation, int index) {
        if (index >= 0) {
            // clone for next recursion
            int[] variationClone = variation.clone();

            // one gets 0, the other 1 at index
            variation[index] = 0;
            variationClone[index] = 1;

            // next recursion
            addVariations(stack, variation, index - 1);
            addVariations(stack, variationClone, index - 1);
        }
        else {
            stack.push(variation);
        }
    }


    static Deque<int[][]> getVariations(int M, int N) {
        int variationLength = M*N;

        // get all variations that the matrices are base on
        // there are n^r, 2^variationLength of them
        Deque<int[]> variations = new ArrayDeque<>();
        addVariations(variations, new int[variationLength], variationLength - 1);

        // container for resulting matrices
        Deque<int[][]> variationMatrices = new ArrayDeque<>();

        // for each matrix
        for (int i = variations.size() - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
            int[][] matrix = new int[N][M];
            int[] variation = variations.pop();

            // for each row add part of variation
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
                matrix[j] = Arrays.copyOfRange(variation, j*M, (j + 1)*M);
            }

            // and push the matrix to result
            variationMatrices.push(matrix);
        }
        return variationMatrices;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = 2, M = 2;
        Deque<int[][]> variations = getVariations(N, M);

        variations.forEach(v -> {
            System.out.println("----");
            for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v[i]));
            }
            System.out.println("----");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I hadn't thought about it this way. Thank you so much!